# Google Maps Javascript API cluster some marker and some not

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I would like to show on Google Map using Javascript API v3 some markers. I have two types of data - vehicle positions and building positions. There's a lot of buildings but only few vehicles. I would like to use clustering algorithm for building markers but not for vehicles. Is it possible using offical Google JS API or using some external library?

Comment: Yes it is possible (but there isn't any clustering built into the Google Maps Javascript API v3).  Add the buildings to the clusterer, don't add the vehicles.

Comment: Possibly related question: [Google Maps API V3: Exclude single marker from clustering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815747/google-maps-api-v3-exclude-single-marker-from-clustering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can distinguish the two different types of markers then you can just do this for the markers regarding buildings (using https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer)

```
var buildingsMarkersArray = [];
...
buildingsMarkersArray.push(someMarker);

// when you are done creating markers then
 var clusterOptions = {
     imagePath: 'the/path/to/images/m'
};

var buildingsCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, buildingsMarkersArray, clusterOptions);
```

This will cluster only the markers you provide.

Comment: That's what I was hoping for :)